Why was the book of Esther included in the canon?
The book of Esther is included in both the Jewish canon and Christian canons of all denominations. However, it seems to have enjoyed a questionable status for much longer than any other of the now-accepted writings. For example, it is the only Old Testament book not to be found at Qumran, it is one of the few OT books not referenced by Sirach, it is omitted from Melito of Sardis's canon, and Athanasius also expressly categorized it with the Apocrypha as useful but not canonical.
Jerome, whose opinion is often cited by Protestants in discussions of the canon, counted Esther as canonical but not the deuterocanonical books (although it seems he changed his opinion on the deuterocanonical books at some point in his career). I haven't read Jerome's comments myself but, usually his reason is explained to be that the canonical books were the ones where the Hebrew manuscripts still existed while the others were only preserved in Greek (or were composed in Greek). However, Jerome seems to have known of Hebrew manuscripts of 1st  Maccabees, so there must be something else going on to distinguish it from Esther.
Protestants usually cite as the main criterion for OT canonicity some prophetic authority guaranteeing the divine inspiration of a book. However, Esther has no association with the prophets, unlike any other book of the Protestant OT canon.
However, Esther was included in the canon by the Council of Rome (382) and by all subsequent streams of Christian thought. Why?  What reasoning lead the Church to set aside the doubts specifically about the book of Esther that apparently had existed for quite a while prior?
This is a historical question. I am not asking why it is included in the canon by Protestants or Catholics today, but rather why it was included starting in the 4th century, i.e. why the doubt which originally surrounded the book was cleared up.

doesn't the book of esther fall under what is considered the histories (same with book of Job) not the prophets?

That's a good point (though Job should be classified in the Wisdom books not histories), but unlike Job and the other non-prophetic books of the OT Esther doesn't even have an association with the prophets (such as Ezra's association with Haggai and Zechariah) to lend authority indirectly

@DarkMalthorp - Ezra had no association with Haggai or Zechariah. H and Z urged the Jews to rebuild the temple.  It was completed and dedicated on March 12th 515 BC julian, Ezra 6:15, using Parker and Dubberstein.  Ezra lead the Jews out of Babylonia, starting 3rd April 458 bc, Gregorian, Ezra 7:9, same P&D chronology.  Ezra completed the book Ezra-Nehemiah about 410 bc, during high priesthood of Jaddua, Nehemiah 12:22. The point is I believe your definition of what constituted a prophet or who was qualified to produce inspired scripture may be too narrow(?). Ezra was qualified, tho' a scribe

Surely what distinguished Esther from 1st Maccabees for Jerome was the opinion of the Jews: they recognised Esther as canonical, but not Maccabees.

This has no bearing on why the Jews came to accept the Book of Esther, but the book has strong Christological characteristics that make it seem inspired.
Read Ahasuerus as God the Father, Vashti as the apostate nation of Israel, Mordechai as Christ, Esther as The Church, the ever-virgin bride of Christ, Haman as Satan, and everything seems very prophetic.

A previously unreadable scroll found at Qumran has recently been shown to be similar (in parts) to the Book of Esther: https://www.thetorah.com/article/newly-deciphered-qumran-scroll-revealed-to-be-megillat-esther

@phantom-99w Hopefully you read at least some of that :-) .|| Letters appearing in brackets have been filled in by scholars. ||  "And [it will be in the days of Ahasuerus]
[he is Ahasuerus the king]
[from Hedo to Cush-sheba]
and [twenty hundred states]
[in those days as a Sabbath]
[king Ahasuerus is] on
[his throne which is]
[in Shushan the capital.]"

Can you add to this question if you're specifically interested in why Esther is on the Protestant canon vs Orthodox/Catholic canon?  I think the reasoning (and therefore the answer) is pretty different depending on perspective.

I am interested in why it was originally included in the canon, in the 4th century and thereabouts.

There are two versions of Esther to bear in mind, the Masoretic Hebrew version and the Greek Septuagint version.  Protestants generally follow the Hebrew version; the Catholic Church follows the Septuagint version.  The masoretic text does not mention God; the Septuagint, which has more chapters, does mention God within its extra chapters.
For the Old Testament, the Protestant churches have taken the canon of the Jews.  The decision has been taken to recognise only those books which have always been recognised by the Jews.  This is despite the fact that when the NT quotes the OT it always(?) quotes the Septuagint.
The definition of allegory includes that allegory is fictional.  But when the Holy Spirit is the author, real historical events can be presented as allegory: a story with a hidden parallel meaning.  Let us call such allegory 'divine allegory': it is true history.
Esther, amongst other things is divine allegory.
There are many "types" of our Lord in the OT.  Noah's Ark, Jacob's ladder, the bronze serpent lifted up in the wilderness, for example.  Many people in the OT are also types of Christ.  Joseph in Egypt, saving the children of Israel from famine, Joshua leading the people into the Promised Land; Melchizedek who brought bread and wine, not the blood of animals, to worship after Abraham's great victory in battle; Solomon is a type for his wisdom.  Now, if you wanted to present a type of the righteousness of Christ, how would you present it?  Let the question be more obvious: if you wanted to present a person who represented the beauty of Christ's righteousness what kind of person would you choose, a man or a woman? How better than a beautiful woman, even a woman who had won, as far as we know, the world's first beauty contest? Esther is a type of Christ, her beauty is a type of the beauty of Christ's righteousness.  "Beginning with Moses and with all the prophets, he explained the things concerning himself in all the scriptures", Luke 24:27.  In all of them we must look for and find Him.
In the days of Xerxes, King Ahasuerus, the people of God, were in danger of annihilation.  They were delivered not by their own moral uprightness, nor by anything in themselves. They were saved by Esther.  The beauty of Esther played a key part in this deliverance: if she had not been beautiful she would not have had any access to the King, to intercede for her people.
In addition to her beauty, she needed great courage, to be willing to die for her people,  "if I perish, I perish", Esth 4v16.
Moving on, let me hazard an interpretation of the casting of the Pur, Esther 3v7. (You decide if it is reasonable.) When the Pur was cast the question always would have two possible answers, usually "yes" or "no".  On the 1st Nisan the Pur was cast for the first time to see if the Jews were to be destroyed that 1st month of Nisan, "yes" or "no". The answer was "no". On the 2nd Nisan, the same question was asked for the 2nd month. Again the answer was "No". The same happened for the first ten days, 1st to the 10th Nisan.  Always the answer was "NO".
On the 11th day the binary question can change.  Haman has already decided that the Jews must be destroyed within the year. So on the 11th day the binary question is "Shall the Jews be eliminated in the 11th month or the 12th month?" The answer was the 12th month. Notice the Pur never said "yes", not even for the 12th month.. God loves his people too much to allow a "yes".. Proverbs 16:33.
So on the 11th the decision is made, the Jews will be destroyed in the 12th month of the same year, the year starting with the month Nisan.  The proclamation probably goes out on the 12th Nisan. It takes a couple of days for Mordecai to learn of it, mourn and put sack cloth on, and persuade Esther to go in to intercede before the King.  Before doing that she asks all to fast for three days, night and day, and she and her maids will do the same.  It is very possible they all fasted from Nisan 14th to 16th, precisely the same days our Lord was in the grave from Friday 14th Nisan to Sunday 16th Nisan.
After his resurrection, our Lord went and is now in Heaven interceding for his people, all who would repent back to God and believe on Our Lord Jesus for salvation.
The usual (Protestant) view is that God does not appear in the book of Esther.  In the Book of Deuteronomy the Lord warned the people:

And the LORD said to Moses, Behold, you will sleep with your fathers; and this people will go a whoring after the gods of the strangers of the land, whither they go to be among them, and will forsake me, and break my covenant which I have made with them.  Then my anger shall be kindled against them in that day, and I will forsake them, and I will hide my face from them, and they shall be devoured, and many evils and troubles shall befall them; so that they will say in that day, Are not these evils come upon us, because our God is not among us? And I will surely hide my face in that day for all the evils which they shall have wrought, in that they are turned unto other gods.  Deuteronomy 31:16-18.

The Masoretic Jews added vowel pointing to the Hebrew text between roughly AD 500 and 1000.  Before this time the Hebrew had no vowel pointing.  Before the vowel pointing the Hebrew for "Esther" was written exactly the same way as the words "I will hide".  In the book God hides himself because of the unfaithfulness of the Jews, but he does not fully abandon them because of his love. (You can see this for yourself: Compare the Hebrew for "I will hide" with "Esther" at www.inter4all.org, deuteronomy 31:17-18 and Esther 2:7. This website obviously shows the vowel pointing of the masoretic text, but you can get the idea by removing the pointing.)
As said already, the usual Protestant view is that God is not mentioned in the Book of Esther.  However, this may not be correct.  It has been known for at least nearly 2000 years that the covenant name for God, Yahweh, or YHWH does appear no less than four times, and the name meaning "I Am" appears once in the text.  These appear as very well hidden acrostics, as described by E. Bullinger in his "The Companion Bible".
In the Hebrew, the four YHWH acrostics are found in chapters 1v20, 5v4, 5v13 and 7v7.  The "I am", EHWH, is found in 7v5, the turning point for the fortunes of the Jews. In each case four consecutive Hebrew words either begin or end(!) with the letters forming the name for G-d, either forwards or backwards(!)
In 1v20, the first letter of four consecutive Hebrew words form YHWH backwards.
In 5v4, the first letter of four consecutive Hebrew words form YHWH forwards.
In 5v13, the last letter of four consecutive Hebrew words form YHWH backwards.
In 7v7 the last letter of four consecutive Hebrew words form YHWH  forwards.
And in 7v5 the four Hebrew words for "Who is he, and where is he" form EHWH, "I am".
To help us, a translation for the four YHWH verses has been suggested (by Bullinger?) with the word LORD used as translation for YHWH:
Due Respect Our Ladies shall give to their husbands, 1v20.
Let Our Royal Dinner this day be graced by the king and haman, 5v4.
yet am i saD, foR nO avaiL is all this to me, 5v13.
for he saw there was eviL tO feaR determineD against him by the king, 7v7.
There is often scepticism about these acrostics. It is natural to wonder whether these acrostics are intended or whether they are wishful thinking: the best test would be to examine 12 other chapters of any other Bible books and see if any similar patterns emerge.  As far as I know no such test has been done.
If these acrostics were truly intended and not accidental then this tells us that the Book of Esther was written especially for a Hebrew speaking audience, namely the Jews.  God's will is that this book be read (and enacted?) every year at the Feast of Purim.  It is for all the Jewish community worldwide. Some Jews are not very religious, and some are hostile to the faith of their ancestors.  By leaving any mention of "God" out of the text the book has been intentionally made palatable to all Jews.. its a great and very entertaining yarn for all Jews, whether they are religious or not.
Throughout the OT era, when an Israelite/Jew were born again through finding faith in the coming Saviour they would remain within Judaism, they would continue to worship in the synagogue and in the Temple amongst their countrymen. They would add spiritual vitality to the religious life of the community.  But ever since our Lord Jesus Christ came and was rejected by that religious system those Jews who have been converted have left Judaism, and they have left the synagogues and joined the Christian community.  The fig tree of Israel has truly been cursed, receiving no spiritual vitality within when a Jew believes on Christ.. they leave the community: and such has been the situation within the Jewish religion since the time of Christ.  And so God saw fit to produce a book that would point to Christ in a hidden form, and make that book exceedingly popular amongst the Jews, so that some by his grace may at some point come to understand they, like us, can only be saved by the righteousness and work of another.  We are not, and cannot be, saved by our own righteousness: we can only be saved by the beautiful, sinless, righteousness of the Messiah.  The Book of Esther, with its hidden spirituality, is the ideal medium as God's testimony of his grace to a graceless people who have turned their back on Him and on the testimony of his true people, the Church.
God has not left them without witness concerning his concern for them.
I believe our job as Christians is to point out to them the Gospel parallels in one of their favourites Hebrew Bible (OT) books.
So, Why is the Book of Esther included in the Canon?
I think we must simply believe that all the books of scripture were recognised by God's people as scripture at the time they were written.  They became canonical perhaps by some official gathering, but the lynchpin of deciding which book to accept as canonical in these meetings must always have been "What have the people of God always viewed about this book?".. and this was their procedure with all of the scriptures.
It was recognised that Mordecai, who wrote the book, was a man of God, and the events that happened were an extraordinary example of God's care for the Jews: God, though not directly mentioned, was working behind the scenes, as it were, to secure the deliverance of his people.
Soon after the events it was recognised there was a supernatural timing in the events.
During those days there were prophets amongst the Jews. These prophets recognised Mordecai as a fellow prophet.  And Mordecai had given the instructions given him by the Lord that the events were to be remembered: this law necessitated that the events be recorded in an inspired book. Esther 9v20-32.
The Protestant Church of the 16th century accepted all the books in the Jewish Canon as canonical.  It is likely Jerome and the Church Fathers in the early Church did the same.

Thank you for the interesting thoughts. However, this doesn't seem to be an answer to my question so much as a commentary on Esther overall.

Reading it, does it not give evidence the book is inspired? What do you think.? The parallels with the character, and mission of our Lord in dying for our sins? The intercession, the being buried 3 days and nights.. it all looks so much Gospel, surely? There is inspired genius in the book, (yes?)

I was asking what evidence did the historical church actually use to incorporate it into the canon. Is there any evidence that these were noticed in the (pre-5th century) ancient Church? I am not asking whether it is inspired.

The evidence is that the Jews said it was inspired.  For Protestants, that is how all the OT books were chosen.

I do now get your objection to my answer..  er ..  Simple solution.. er.. change the question? :)

@AndrewShanks  I was revisiting the book of Esther and had a couple of questions to ask. It seems the answers to my unposted question are already here. Guess I will just have to go back to the drawing board and come up with a new question! Perhaps something about seeing the book of Esther as divine allegory as opposed to a record of actual events? Or perhaps I should ask this on the Jewish site?

https://www.academia.edu/6370833/Desperately_Seeking_YHWH_Finding_God_in_Esthers_Acrostics_?email_work_card=view-paper You might be interested in this.

@DarkMalthorp - Thanks! Great work, and perfectly relevant find!  Bushell, Tan and Weaver's Bibleworks sounds very useful.  If you don't mind I will postscript my answer with data from the article.  The author has done some wonderful analysis with great software, but, IMO, his conclusions are dubious.  Thankfully, he has given us the data on which we can draw our own conclusions.

I think I will follow your suggestion and ask another question that this would be more suitable for.

Philip Schaff writes an excellent summary of this issue here.
He notes the "silent period" from about Malachi to the forerunner as the absence of the prophetical spirit.  Maccabees even mentions this, saying it is not the same as the canonical books.
He also mentions Esther and Melito as most likely a simple overlook as Melito lists 21 books, rather than the 22 of Josephus.  Origen mentions 22 including Esther, but differs elsewhere.
The question of a Palestinian and Alexandrian canon is further addressed, being basically identical per Philo.

OP: What reasoning lead the Church to set aside the doubts specifically about the book of Esther that apparently had existed for quite a while prior?

As mentioned, the history of Esther is not that oblique.  It fits into the various early lists.  It was written about 4th century BC during the prophetic period.  Schaff speaks about Jerome's list as identical to the most likely specific canonical list of Josephus.
In short, the early Church recognized the Jewish canon, including Esther, extant in Christ's time and the reason it was considered the canon and not others.
